# Problems with arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

Given a shifted array (for example):

```
[17 34 190 1 4]
```

which shifted from (we don't know original)

```
[1 4 17 34 190]
```

What would be a good function to find the position of that number?

For example if I pass 1, it would return 3th position.

Comment: Looks very like a homework question, mark it as such if it is. More info would be useful

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually, this looks like an interview question.  Why the negs guys?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: Because it's blatantly asking for someone else to code it for him?

Answer (score 1):

linear search for answer would always work, but I believe you can get there in O(log) time.

Some sort of binary search for the shift point via checking if the value of the shift sorted array goes against what it is supposed it.  Like creating a trie.  Keep forming the sorted tree until you find the "illegal" node (man this is glossing over a lot of details - I know).  That tells you where the inflection point is and you now treat the array as 2 sorted vectors.  Quickly check to see if the value to find is larger than the max entry of each so we know which vector to search.  BSearch the sorted vector for your value and return its index.

The hard part is finding the inflection point.  :)

Comment: Well, also the inflection point can be found in O(log n) time. +1 for the interesting twist :-)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to scan the array.

```
size_t pos_in_arr(int *arr, size_t arr_size, int match)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
        if (arr[i] == match)
            break;
    return i;
}
```

This function would return the position as asked, or one more than the maximum position in case the element is not found.

The solution is what you *ask*, but it is probably not what you *need*, because it does not use in any way the fact that the array has been shifted. I suspect the original problem to be more complex.

For example *if* you knew that in the original array one element was fifth and now is seventh, and the element you are looking for was twenty-third, you could answer "twenty-fifth" without actually scanning the array up to the twenty-fifth position, which could be the point of the whole exercise. But to build such a solution, one would need to know more about the problem.